# Create dataframe columns from JSON within CSV column

Tags: python, dataframe, json-normalize

Good day all!
I am trying to flatten some nested JSON using json_normalize, but I the output I keep getting is not what I need.
Here's my code so far:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('data_file.csv')

groups_dict = df1['groups']
df2 = pd.json_normalize(groups_dict)
```

The bit where the dictionary gets created seems to be working as seen here:

```
groups_dict.info()
groups_dict.head()

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
RangeIndex: 19 entries, 0 to 18
Series name: groups
Non-Null Count  Dtype 
--------------  ----- 
19 non-null     object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 280.0+ bytes

0   [{'group_id': 798800, 'name': 'Clickers 1 '}]
1   [{'group_id': 798803, 'name': 'Clickers 2'}]
2   [{'group_id': 848426, 'name': 'Colin Safe Brow...
3   [{'group_id': 798804, 'name': 'Clickers 3'}]
4   [{'group_id': 855348, 'name': 'Email Whitelist...
Name: groups, dtype: object
```

But when I try to normalize the dictionary, I get the following output:

```
df2 = pd.json_normalize(groups_dict)
df2.head()

0
1
2
3
4
```

I need to have each item from the groups column listed as it's own column to complete my project. Please see example below for sample data file (csv format) and what I am trying to accomplish.

CSV:

```
campaign_id,name,groups,status,content,duration_type,start_date,end_date,relative_duration,auto_enroll,allow_multiple_enrollments,completion_percentage
201644,Clicker 1 Retraining ,"[{'group_id': 798800, 'name': 'Clickers 1 '}]",Closed,"[{'store_purchase_id': 1076203, 'content_type': 'Store Purchase', 'name': 'Spot the Phish Game: Foundational', 'description': 'Make sure you can spot a phishing attempt by using this condensed Spot the Phish game. With ten...', 'type': 'Game', 'duration': 5, 'retired': False, 'retirement_date': None, 'publish_date': '2020-10-02T17:08:16.000Z', 'publisher': 'APP1', 'purchase_date': '2022-04-13T00:00:00.000Z', 'policy_url': None}]",Relative End Date,2022-04-19T08:00:00.000Z,,1 weeks,TRUE,FALSE,14
201645,Clicker 2 Retraining  ,"[{'group_id': 798803, 'name': 'Clickers 2'}]",In Progress,"[{'store_purchase_id': 1060139, 'content_type': 'Store Purchase', 'name': 'Micro-module – Social Engineering', 'description': 'This five-minute micro-module defines social engineering and describes what criminals are after....', 'type': 'Training Module', 'duration': 5, 'retired': False, 'retirement_date': None, 'publish_date': '2020-09-09T16:06:01.000Z', 'publisher': 'APP2', 'purchase_date': '2022-03-21T00:00:00.000Z', 'policy_url': None}]",Relative End Date,2022-04-13T08:00:00.000Z,,1 weeks,TRUE,FALSE,0
```

Before script:

```
df1['groups'].head()

0   [{'group_id': 798800, 'name': 'Clickers 1 '}]
1   [{'group_id': 798803, 'name': 'Clickers 2'}]
2   [{'group_id': 848426, 'name': 'Colin Safe Brow...
3   [{'group_id': 798804, 'name': 'Clickers 3'}]
4   [{'group_id': 855348, 'name': 'Email Whitelist...
Name: groups, dtype: object
```

After script:

```
df2.head()

   group_id   name
0  798800     Clickers 1
1  798803     Clickers 2
2  848426     Colin Safe Brow...
3  798804     Clickers 3
4  855348     Email Whitelist...
```

Anyone have pointers on how I should proceed?

Any assistance would be greatly appreaciated. Thanks!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please do not post images of code or output. Visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have edited the original post to include text for code inputs and outputs.

Comment: Please post a sample of the file, so people can reproduce the problem and test fixes

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos, I've added a link to the file with the sample data.

Comment: Post a sample of the file in the question itself. Links can get broken and most people *won't* follow links to unknown sites

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos

I have edited again to reflect latest feedback. The "Before script" section shows data that needs to be changed.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Post a sample of the actual data, something others can use to test solutions. If you have a file with one JSON object per line you need `read_json` not `read_csv`. `json_normalize` works only on lists and dictionaries, not Series.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73907221/5901382

Comment: If you have a JSON object per line you can use `pd.read_json(path,orient='records',lines=True)`. Right now it's not clear even if you have a JSON string or a Python dictionary. The (probably incorrect) duplicate works if you have a dictionary.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - The csv data has been added. Hopefully it's what you were referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first extract the nested dict from its `str` representation by using `eval` or `ast.literal_eval` from the `ast` module.

You can then create a separate dataframe from the column you want by doing:

```py
import ast

df1['groups'] = df1['groups'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

However, this returns a list of a single dict in your dataset. To combat this, we'll extract the first element of each row.

```py
df1['groups'] = df1['groups'].apply(lambda l: l[0])

df2 = df1['groups'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Then you can access individual columns such as `group_id` and `name` using:

```py
df2['group_id']
df2['name']  # etc.
```

```
   group_id
0  798800
1  798803
2  848426
3  798804
4  855348
```

Similarly for other columns within your nested dict.

Comment: Thanks! 

I just tried and I get this error on the `df2 = df1['groups'].apply(pd.Series, axis=1)` bit now:

`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`

Comment: When I tested with the `axis` removed, I get this as output:

                                                              `0
0  {'group_id': 798800, 'name': 'Clickers 1 '}
1  {'group_id': 798803, 'name': 'Clickers 2'}`

Comment: @mm_ss.0291 I've added the necessary changes. It should be working now

Comment: It works! You are an awesome human being!

Comment: If it worked for your problem then consider marking it as accepted.